# Calculate eccentricity from apside altitudes?

Tags: orbit, earth, orbital-elements, orbital-mechanics, satellite

I need to calculate the eccentricity of a satellite orbit with only the apside altitudes (height above the surface of the Earth), 400 and 1500 km. However, I don't know the semi-major axis ($a$) or semi-minor axis ($b$).

$$\text{eccentricity} = (1-(b/a)^2)^{1/2}$$

Comment: Why would you *need* to do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this was cross posted on Physics SE.

Comment: @JamesK I need the eccentricity and semi-major axis to input into an orbit generation/propagation code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major axis is just the sum of the distance at perigee plus the distance at apogee. This is 400 km + 1500 km + the *diameter* (not radius) of the Earth, and the semi-major axis is half of that.

However, the semi-minor axis is harder to determine. Therefore, why not use an [alternative method to calculate the eccentricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_eccentricity#Calculation)?

$$e = \frac{r_a-r_p}{r_a+r_p}$$

Here, the $r$'s are the distance to the *center* of the Earth, not the apside altitudes. Can you take it from here?